# Batch compiling several files with Latexmk.exe

Tags: compiling, latexmk

For compiling many files from different directories I created the list of the files and pass it as an argument `%1` to batch file:

```
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (%1) DO latexmk.exe -pdf -shell-escape -outdir="%%~dpi"  "%%i"
```

where `%%i` - is the variable, which is contain file full path  (e.g. `e:\...\...\...\file.tex`)

I want that any outputed files generated with `pdflatex` are placed in the same directory as the main tex-file (I realized it with `-outdir="%%~dpi"`)

Unfortunately, I get an `latexmk.exe` error:

> No file name specified, and I couldn't find any

bat-file output is:

```
    D:\Programs\ScriptFiles>latexmk.exe -pdf -shell-escape -outdir="e:\RightTeXFiledir\"  "e:\RightTeXFiledir\file.tex"
runscript.tlu:679: command failed with exit code 10:
latexmk.pl -pdf -shell-escape -outdir="e:\RightTeXFiledir\"  "e:\RightTeXFiledir\file.tex"
```

When I remove `-outdir="%%~dpi"` from batch file, The compilation successful, but all generated files placed in the batch-file directory.

**How can I specify the output directory same as the compiled tex-file?**

It is interesting to note, the straightforward compiling with `pdflatex` does not produce any error:

```
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i IN (%1) DO %TexDistr%\pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -time-statistics -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=%%~dpi -shell-escape  "%%i"
```

But the problem with this way is a lack of bibtex.exe  launching.

Comment: Have you tried outputting a command-sequence which is actually run? What is the actual call?

Comment: @TeXnician The batch-file outdir seems right. I have added bath-file terminal output

Comment: It would probably be wise to `cd /d ` to the directory and then compile for each file. Would that be an option?

Comment: @TeXnician Where should I put `cd /d` to?

Comment: It should be within the loop (of course you have to give the directory parameter). Something like `FOR ... DO (cd /d ... latexmk ...)` with a new line between parameter of `cd` and `latexmk`.

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you. Interesting solution. I will try.